# jQuery UI Datepicker: how to set container's display to flex?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

as the title says, I want Datepicker's "ui-datepicker-div" to be set as flex. My goal is to create a lightbox, but I don't how to accomplish this easily. I did some experiments in jquery ui's code to understand, why it does not work the way it is supposed to. I tried "beforeShow" by overriding "display", but no luck.

In the end the result of the inline-css created by Datepicker is always "block", although console.log tells me that it is set to "flex" (inside beforeShow).

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a CSS rule that overrides display? Either redefine that very class in your stylesheet, or add another class to your Datepicker container and redefine display on that class. Remember CSS decides which property's value to use based on how specific the selector is. I mean, properties in `div.my-class{}` would override `.myclass{}`

Comment: @FabioLolli: This is not possible because as far as i know inline css rules any other defined css. Datepicker display is set through inline css ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do this with JavaScript and the inline css keeps getting in your way, you could try removing the inline css completely by using `$myDatepickerReference.removeAttr('style')` but that would remove all of the Datepicker's inline css. Or you could read the value of 'style', remove the part where display is specified, and set the correct value with `$myDatepickerReference.attr('style', newValue)`

If you're desperate specifying `!important` in your css doc after the property will make it override every other class property of the same type - you could try if in this way it works as you want, then from there proceed to identify what the problem is. If it does not work in this way either, there's probably some other kind of error somewhere

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
    display: flex !important;
}
```

Reponse to comment:

I think the problem is the `!important` clause in display property will keep overriding the value even when the datepicker should be closed - meaning `display: none` will not hide it anymore. What you could do, is create a new class

```
.my-flex-datepicker {
    display: flex !important;
}
```

and then in the open and close event of the datepicker, respectively add and remove this new class to `$('#ui-datepicker-div')`

Comment: The "!important" works very well:-) Thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work completely well - At first glance, this seems to work, but after fading in, the window keeps open, no matter I choose a date.

Comment: Mmh I think that's because it will override `display: none` too... You could try adding a class with the `!important` bit to your datepicker in the open event, and remove that class in the close event.

Comment: I think, now I got it :-) In addition to your answer, you set the class with "beforeShow" attribute and remove it with "onClose". Anyways, thank you for your help!